# how to prevent windows server 2008 from automatically ending user sessions

Tags: windows, visual-studio, session, windows-server-2008-r2

i am connected to a windows server 2008 R2 server using a terminal TC (thin client). all of our applications are running on the server and if a user is idle for more than 5 minutes, his session will be ended and he will be loged out.

i want to write a program and run it to prevent server from ending my session. i tried using apis for moving the cursor and sending keys to windows but it did not prevented the server from ending the session so what should i do?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: @Sina that's not the way it should be done!

Answer (score 2):

This is a setting created by your server admin. I would have a word with them about getting it changed instead of trying to hack round it

Comment: You should configure your Terminal Services or Remote Desktop Services for R2 to just let you idle. It's standard setting you can tweak.